# Do we know what happened to this character in Avengers: Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

There is a lot of time travel involved in *Avengers: Endgame* and with it brings

> Gamora back into the fold.

We know what happened to the character in *Avengers: Infinity War* but in *Endgame*

> A past version is brought to the present in the fight against Thanos.

This character helps out but is last seen

> with all the other female Avengers assisting Captain Marvel in getting the gauntlet to the quantum tunnel.

As the character is then missing at the end of the movie do we know what happened to them?

> <sub>*FWIW I think finding Gamora will probably play a part in GotG3 with the setup at the end of Endgame so I’m specifically asking for any evidence we currently know of for what happened to her.*</sub>

Comment: You should re-watch the movie. Gamora actually meets with Star Lord where they have a face to face conversation, with her asking Nebula if "this is the man".

Comment: @Lefteris008 Ah true it was 4am and I'd just got home after seeing it so had a brain fart. However, she is missing later on at the final events of the film so it's not clear what happened to her after the battle and Tony's actions.

Comment: Tony actually snapped Gamora out of existence. Because he didn't know Gamora was in their side.

Comment: @Lobo I don't think Gamora was snapped because I think tony snapped away the army of Thanos and Gamora was not a part of Thanos's army at the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Gamora from the 2014 timeline, who traveled to the main timeline in *Avengers: Endgame*, survived the final battle in *Endgame* and stayed in the main timeline. In *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3* (2023), she is revealed to have joined the Ravagers. [James Gunn has confirmed via his Twitter account](https://twitter.com/JamesGunn/status/1656728912137977857) that this is the same Gamora from *Avengers: Endgame*:

> **iAm_No0ne_:** […] Is GotG 3 Gamora the same Gamora that was in the Battle of Endgame?

> **JamesGunn:** Yes.

Answer (score 11):

I think it's a little unclear, although it seems that the character continues to exist in the present.  I base this on the character's last appearance (which occurs after that which you cited) and what followed:

> We last see past-Gamora as Quill encounters her near the finish, I think, of the big climactic battle, after she and present-Nebula have killed past-Nebula.  (I've seen it once so I'm relying on imperfect memory here.)  As he touches her cheek, past-Gamora kicks Quill in the nether regions (twice).  Then she asks Nebula, "This one, really?"  Nebula answers, "It was either him or a tree."  This gives the impression that Nebula has, off screen, already told Gamora about her relationship with Quill.  Having now met Quill, past-Gamora is not impressed.  I also had the impression that past-Gamora survived the battle, although we don't see this on-screen.  The moment where we see Quill searching for her, immediately before bantering with Thor, suggests to me that past-Gamora has stayed in the present but slipped away rather than joining the Guardians.  However, that's merely an interpretation.  I do agree it potentially sets up "Guardians of the Galaxy 3: The Search for Gamora."

One of the deleted scenes to be included on the DVD of Endgame was released on July 26, 2019.  It reveals that Gamora survived Tony's snap and shows her turning and possibly walking away from the battlefield.  Source: [USA Today article with scene](https://www.usatoday.com/story/entertainment/movies/2019/07/26/endgame-avengers-salute-their-fallen-exclusive-deleted-scene/1827992001/).

Comment: Hmmm it is a potential idea that she just didn't want to stay with the GotG but I get the feeling she would have stayed with Nebula if not for Quill. Still +1 though seems like some decent reasoning.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Agreed.  I was a bit surprised to see Nebula with the GotG, but not Gamora.  The "why" of her decision not to stay with Nebula, despite Quill, gets into speculation about her motivations, and what the writers were thinking.  It would have been nice to have seen a moment explaining it.

Comment: “Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 3: *How* is Gamora?” (Spoiler: she’s fine.)

Comment: @Rob bear in mind it’s 2014 Gamora. Although she allied with Nebula to stop Thanos, there’s still a lot of animosity between them at this point.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite That's how I interpreted it, too: she wouldn't have been ready to be a sister to Nebula, not having lived those four years' worth of experiences with the GotG as well has her.  Although this makes the most sense to me, I suppose her motivation to leave could also have included a desire to take a gap year to see the universe, grief for the loss of her dad Thanos, or an unrequited lust for Rocket.

Comment: It's also possible that 2014 Gamora is not in the present day (she may have been snapped if Tony's snap was "send anything from 2014 back to the timeline it came from", or due to returning of the Stones to the moment they were taken), and Quill is just searching for her on a hope and a dream that, with the Soul Stone destroyed, she is somehow alive again.  Because I doubt she would have gotten away from Earth so easily the Guardians ship was having trouble finding her if she still existed, and if time travel wasn't a thing in the movie I imagine Quill would still be looking for her in the end

Comment: Was Gammora at starks funeral? If she wasn’t then that suggests she had left earth. Remember to her the guardians are strangers and nebula is not the close sister she becomes. She may well need to go off and find herself.

Comment: @RichardC No she wasn't. So she indeed likely went away after the battle while the GotG stayed to discuss a few things and pay respect to Iron Man.

Comment: @JimmyM. I think it was pretty clear that Thanos and co. got turned into dust, not transported to another timeline.

Answer (score 5):

My take on it is that there's a possibility that they'd take a page from the *Infinity Wars* comic.

> In the comics Gamora looked for her other counterpart trapped in soul world. Well it was really part of her but maybe in the MCU they might make it so that Gamora from the past wants to meet the other Gamora. It might be an interesting take given how the Infinity Stones work there. It also makes it possible to play with the other alternate dimensions such as having Loki back

Comment: Also worth noting that in the Infinity Gauntlet series, Gamora and Adam Warlock both start as being trapped in the soul gem and manage to escape. The GotG 2 hinted at the possibility Adam Warlock, and he's always been linked to the soul gem, so I think there is a lot of comics precedent for them going down this path. Still speculation though.